# How do I view the results of the compiled python?

Tags: python, json

I am trying to run the python program from a git repository but I am not understanding where the results are displayed or suppose to be as I want to be able to put the results into a list for a database.

the repository: [LINK to Repository](https://github.com/AndrewLien/UCSC_Courses_API)

when i run the python program i get this but do not see a .txt file or anywhere that shows the reults 
[image]

I am fairly new to programming so thanks for any help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Python questions are off-topic here, you might have more luck at StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3):

There is hint `Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000`. The program is a web server. Point your browser to the address. To stop the server type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in the console.